Convolution of unit step function with the mirror image of unit step function
What will be the convolution of u(t) with u(-t) using convolution integral? I am confused about the limits of the integration.

It doesn't exist (diverges).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

convolution of u(t) with itself would exist and would be 0 for t < 0 and t for t >= 0,  but convoulution of 2 function u(t) and v(t)=u(-t) would diverge.  there is always an infinitely large part where both functions overlap.
